# Finding VBS xpath for API call

Tags: asp.net, xpath, vbscript

I have been trying to find and print out the time spent on a project and print it out on a web page. No matter what I try, it refuses to cooperate with me. I've marked where I am having problems like *problem code*. My problem code is:

```
'****Get hours spent on project
postUrl = "https://api.dovico.com/TimeEntries/Employee/{sEmployeeID}/?version=4"
Set xmlHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHTTP.open "GET", postUrl, false
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "WRAP
access_token=""client = 52ced897fb6b404f87cfe70e84bed1b4.15731&user_token = 6d0a58751f5f4d619cce65c5cc52b420.15731"""
xmlHTTP.send
set mytime = xmlHTTP.responseXML
*hours =  mytime.selectsingleNode("//TimeEntries/Employees/Employee:{274}").item(0)*
Response.write "Number of hours spend on project is: " & hours
```

Can anyone please help. This is kind of my hail marry pass here.

Comment: Please let us know what results you are seeing. Unexpected output? No output? Also, maybe elaborate on what else you've tried.

Comment: This : `//TimeEntries/Employees/Employee:{274}` doesn't look like a valid standard XPath. What you mean by the last part : `Employee:{274}`?

Comment: Its probably obvious that I'm very new to this. I was trying to follow the path with 274 being the employee number. The reason for the : is because it asks for a node test when I use a / (with or without the brackets) and even then I still get msxml6.dll error '80004005'
Expected token 'EOF' found ':'. Result/TimeEntries/Employees/Employee-->:<--{274}